# Unable to map land surface temperature in QGIS from downloaded tiff

Tags: qgis, landsat, land-surface-temperature

I am trying to download a land surface temperature raster layer from USGS Earth Explorer. I have chosen the following data to map for the Berkeley, CA. From Earth Explorer, from Landsat 4-9 C2 U.S. ARD data - ARD Tile Surface Temperature files, I have chosen to download `ST_B10.TIF`, because I think this is the raster file that would simply show land surface temperature in Kelvin. And so I download the file as "LC09_CU_002009_20231116_20231120_02_ST_B10.TIF"

I now want to view this land surface temperature raster file in QGIS.
I open QGIS 3.14 and a new project.
I then search for my new TIFF file and click to open it.

I am then presented with this "Select Transformation" popup, which I do not understand:
[image]

Not understanding which transformation to choose, or what accuracy in meters means here, I just opt for the already-highlighted first one and click OK.

And to my surprise, I do not see anything appear, except for a tiny smudge of pixels in the lower right corner:
[image]

Zoomed in this smudge looks like this:
[image]

And further, I see the scale is 22220 to 25143, which does not make sense to me. I thought this scale was going to be in Kelvin.

How can I fix my process for viewing this land surface temperature TIFF in QGIS so that I can properly see the high-resolution 30m land surface temperature for the East Bay region of California? The purpose of this task is for visualizing the local urban heat island effect.

Comment: Can you provide a direct link where you downloaded the tiff? It's quite cumbersome to navigate through Earth Explorer to try to find the file which you mean and without having the file, testing is not possible.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not seeing an actual link to the specific data download I got besides just earthexplorer.usgs.gov, but here is the path I took for the download, I just drew a circle around Berkeley, CA > Apply > Data Sets > Landsat > Landsat C2 U.S. Analysis Ready Data (ARD) > Landsat 4-9 C2 U.S. ARD > Results > Tile ID: LC09_CU_002009_20231116_20231120_02 > Download > ARD Tile Surface Temperature > Select Files > ST_B10.TIF > Download. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the thumbnails and the metadata before you download.

You've downloaded a tile that contains only a tiny amount of data in the bottom corner from the edge of a Landsat path.  If you want data for that tile, you'll need to choose a different date.

Additionally, that image is stated to have 100% cloud cover.

[image]
[image]

[image]

The data is in degrees Kelvin, but you need to apply the scale factor and offset per the [documentation](https://www.usgs.gov/media/files/landsat-collection-2-us-analysis-ready-data-dfcb), i.e. `DN * 0.00341802 + 149.0`.

[image]

Lastly you are presented with the "Select Transformation" popup because your QGIS Project has the map CRS set to [EPSG:2263 (NAD83 / New York Long Island)](https://epsg.io/2263) and the tile is in a different projection and requires a datum transformation to display.  I don't know why you set your map CRS to one that is appropriate for an area on the opposite side of the continent.